# How can I return a status from an Azure Power Automate PowerShell script to Flow

Tags: powershell, return-value, power-automate, azure-automation

I've created a simple PowerShell script, hosted in an Azure Automation Account

I have created a Webhook and this is used in a Flow (Power Automate) HTTP call

This all works fine, so far. But how can I return a value (at minimum a pass / fail status) back to Flow?

Comment: What purpose does the PowerShell script serve?  Meaning, what exactly does it do?  I ask because depending on what it does, you may be able to achieve the same thing via an alternative means and get the output you want.

Comment: It manages External Identities, in AD; AFAIK, there is no API to achieve this, nor any other way ...

Comment: Ok, cool.  I trust you and won't bother looking into it otherwise but the path of using an Azure Functions PowerShell approach was on my mind.  You can easily return values to the calling application when using that approach.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can use Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/samlorwsfedexternaldomainfederation-post-domains?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, but since I have the PowerShell working, if I can implement a return value then all good - but how?

Comment: Using an Azure function sounds like it’s definitely worth a shot and there’s a PowerShell library you may be able to use … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-1.0 … you just need to do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I can answer my question as follows

The core point is that Flow supports an "Azure Automation" step (Premium) that can call a Runbook directly, and more importantly, can see a return status

There is a option to "Wait" i.e. operate synchronously, which allows easy error handling

By using "Throw" in the PowerShell, it is possible to trigger a Fail status

This is much superior to the Webhook, I'd tried earlier, as it means the Powershell script can be kept simple and the Flow can handle any error condition e.g. by logging or messaging ...